# One continuous variable and one categorical variable (with four categories)

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data, continuous-data, variable

I have a dataset and want to see whether participants’ happiness ratings were affected by the season they were interviewed in? How do I do that in R since my categorical variable has four levels?

Comment: ANOVA: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/one-way-anova-test-in-r

Comment: The simplest way would be, `anova(DV ~ IV, data = your_data)`. Most likely you will want to do post-hoc tests, adjust for error, etc.

Comment: @HanselPalencia: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be, `anova(DV ~ IV, data = your_data)`. Most likely you will want to do post-hoc tests, adjust for error, etc.

EDIT: Posting as the answer by recommendation of @Stephan Kolassa.